# Use Checkbox to Insert or Delete a row in Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I am trying to update a single record in a DataList. I have chosen the `DataList` type so that I can have a horizontal row with many records on the same page, can use the page to take attendance from a pre-determined list of people, but I want to update as I go. I will be using volunteers to take attendance and don't want to force the users to click save after they are finished (They may get distracted and forget to do so).  So, each check box marks a person present. Or unchecking marks them absent.

Here is my CSHTML page:

```
      <%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="AttendanceTaking.aspx.cs" Inherits="AtChurch.AttendanceTaking" %>
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
        <style>.ChkBoxClass input {width:25px; height:25px;}
        .auto-style1 {
            width: 32px;
        }
        .auto-style2 {
            width: 183px;
        }
    </style>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="auto-style2"><strong>Take Attendance</strong></td>
                <td class="auto-style1">Date:</td>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAttendanceDate" runat="server"></asp:Label>
                    </strong>
                </td>
                <td>
                    Attendance Group:</td>
                <td>
                    <strong>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblAttendanceGroup" runat="server" ></asp:Label>
                    </strong>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>
        <p>
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenAttendanceDate" runat="server" />
            <asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenSoCID" runat="server" />
        </p>
        <p>
            <asp:DataList RepeatDirection="Horizontal" RepeatColumns="6" ID="DataList1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" OnSelectedIndexChanged="DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Both">
                <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#000066" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#006699" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <ItemStyle ForeColor="#000066" />
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPresent" runat="server" RowNumber='<%# Eval("RowNumber") %>' AttendanceID='<%# Eval("AttendanceID") %>' PeopleId='<%# Eval("PeopleID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("CheckBoxPresent") %>' Checked='<%# Eval("CheckBoxPresent").ToString().Equals("1") %>' CssClass="ChkBoxClass" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxPresent_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  />
  <asp:Label ID="RowNumber" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RowNumber") %>'  />                   
 <asp:Label ID="FullName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("FullName") %>'  />
                     <asp:Label ID="PeopleID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PeopleID") %>'  />
                    <asp:Label ID="AttendanceID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("AttendanceID") %>' ></asp:Label>
                    <asp:Label ID="AttendLabel" runat="server" Text="&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp&nbsp"></asp:Label> <br />
    <br />
                </ItemTemplate>
                <SelectedItemStyle BackColor="#669999" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <FooterTemplate>
                    :
                </FooterTemplate>
            </asp:DataList>
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:AtChurchConString %>" SelectCommand="sp_AttendanceTaking" SelectCommandType="StoredProcedure">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ChurchID" DefaultValue="0" Name="ChurchID" PropertyName="Value" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenSoCID" DefaultValue="0" Name="HiddenSoCID" PropertyName="Value" />
                    <asp:Parameter DefaultValue="1" Name="Select" Type="Int32" />
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="HiddenAttendanceDate" DefaultValue="" Name="AttendanceDate" PropertyName="Value" Type="DateTime" />
                    <%--<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="CheckBoxPresent" DefaultValue="0" Name="CheckBoxPresent" PropertyName="Value" />--%>
                   <%-- <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="AttendanceID" DefaultValue="0" Name="AttendanceID" PropertyName="Value" />--%>
                    <%--<asp:ControlParameter ControlID="PeopleID" DefaultValue="0" Name="PeopleID" PropertyName="Value" />--%>
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>

            <asp:HiddenField ID="ChurchID" runat="server" />



        </p>
        <p>
            &nbsp;</p>
        </asp:Content>
```

And here is my CS page:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Configuration;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace AtChurch
{
    public partial class AttendanceTaking : System.Web.UI.Page

    {
        private static string strcon = WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AtChurchConString"].ConnectionString;



        // Need these for Security
        public string strRole, strChurchID, strAttGroup, strAttDate;
        public bool ValidUser { get; private set; }




        // Checkbox Checked?
        protected void CheckBoxPresent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //start of checkbox
            CheckBox ChkBxPresent = sender as CheckBox;
            Boolean ChkBxPresentState = ChkBxPresent.Checked;


            //DataList1.DataBind();

            foreach (DataListItem itm in DataList1.Items)
            {


                if (itm.ItemType == ListItemType.Item )
                {
                    string strPeopleID = ((Label)itm.FindControl("PeopleID")).Text;
                    string strAttendanceID = ((Label)itm.FindControl("AttendanceID")).Text;


                    Response.Write(strPeopleID);
                    Response.End();

                    //string strAttID = "";
                    //strAttID = ((DataBoundLiteralControl)item.Controls[1]).Text;


                    if (ChkBxPresentState == true)
                {
                    Response.Write("Let's Insert it...");
                    Response.Write(strPeopleID); 

                    Response.End();
                }
                else
                {
                //Response.Write("Let's Remove it...");
                //Response.End();

                SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                // First let's delete this Groups Data

                SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand("sp_AttendanceTaking", con);
                cmdDelete.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                //cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@HiddenSoCID", SqlDbType.Int));
                cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AttendanceID", SqlDbType.Int));
                //cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChurchID", SqlDbType.Int));
                //cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AttendanceDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));
                cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@CheckBoxPresent", SqlDbType.Int));
                        //cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PeopleID", SqlDbType.Int));


                        // Convert Strings to Int where needed 
                        if (Int32.TryParse(strAttendanceID.ToString(), out int intAttendanceID)) { }



                        Response.Write(intAttendanceID);
                        Response.Write("-");
                        Response.Write(1);
                        Response.End();

                        cmdDelete.Parameters["@AttendanceID"].Value = intAttendanceID;
                        cmdDelete.Parameters["@CheckBoxPresent"].Value = 0;


                con.Open();
                cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                        // End delete data

                    }
                }

        }
//end of checkbox 

        }





        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)

        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {


                // Get Attendance Group ID from the Attendance page.

                //if (Request.QueryString["SoCID"].ToString() != null && Request.QueryString["SoCID"].ToString() != null)
                string SoCID = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["SoCID"]);
                string AttendanceDate = Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["AttendanceDate"]);
               // Response.Write("ok?"+AttendanceDate);
               // Response.End();

                if (SoCID != null && AttendanceDate != null)
                {
                    strAttGroup = SoCID;
                    HiddenSoCID.Value = strAttGroup;
                    lblAttendanceGroup.Text = strAttGroup;

                    strAttDate = AttendanceDate;
                    HiddenAttendanceDate.Value = strAttDate;
                    lblAttendanceDate.Text = strAttDate;


                    //strAttDate =  Request.QueryString["AttendanceDate"].ToString();

                    //Response.Write(strAttGroup);
                    //Response.Write(strAttDate);
                    //Response.End();

                }

                else
                {
                    //Response.Write("error");

                    Response.Redirect("Attendance.aspx");
                    Response.End();
                }

            }


            // Security Start
            if (Session["Role"] is null && Session["ChurchID"] is null)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
                return;
            }


            if (Session["Role"] != null && Session["ChurchID"] != null)
            {
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Session["Role"].ToString()))
                {
                    strRole = Session["Role"].ToString();
                    strChurchID = Session["ChurchID"].ToString();
                }
            }

            if (strRole == ("SuperAdmin") || strRole == ("ChurchAdmin"))
            {
                ValidUser = true;
            }

            if (ValidUser != true)
            {
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            }
            // Security End

            //Populate the ChurchID for Insert
            ChurchID.Value = strChurchID;
        }

            protected void DataList1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        protected void Button_AttendanceTaker_Command(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

This is just the button code of which I am working with to add or delete using my stored procedure.

```
    protected void CheckBoxPresent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //start of checkbox
            CheckBox ChkBxPresent = sender as CheckBox;
            Boolean ChkBxPresentState = ChkBxPresent.Checked;
            // I added this to try to compare to to get a specific row for Insert
            string BoxIndex = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["RowNumber"];

            //DataList1.DataBind();

            foreach (DataListItem itm in DataList1.Items)
            {


                // I added this to try to compare to within the Item List
                string ItmIndex = ((Label)itm.FindControl("RowNumber")).Text; 


                if (itm.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
                {
                // Let's gather the parameter data needed
                    string strPeopleID = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["PeopleId"];
                    string strAttendanceID = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["AttendanceID"];
                    string strCheckBoxPresent = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["IsChecked"];
                    string strAttGroupID = ((Label)itm.FindControl("SoCID")).Text;
                    string strAttendanceDate = ((Label)itm.FindControl("AttendanceDate")).Text;

                    // Here is what we do if the box is checked...

                    // I used this to try and compare the values.  It showed the one I wanted to 
                    // compare to but the ItmIndex only returned odd rows.  So I don't match somtimes

                    //Response.Write("BoxIdx=");
                    //Response.Write(BoxIndex);
                    //Response.Write("and  ItmIdx=");
                    //Response.Write(ItmIndex);


                    // I added the compare of ItmIndex == BoxIndex but it was not consistent.  Again it was only returning odd
                    // numbers and no even numbers to compare to for some reason.

                    if (ChkBxPresentState == true)
                    {
                        string strAction = "ADD";


                        //Response.Write("Add BoxIdx=");
                        //Response.Write(BoxIndex);
                        //Response.Write("and  ItmIdx=");
                        //Response.Write(ItmIndex);



                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

                        //Response.Write("Let's Insert it...");
                        //Response.Write("PeopleID");
                        //Response.Write(strPeopleID);
                        //Response.Write("ChurchID");
                        //Response.Write(strChurchID);
                        //Response.Write("GroupID");
                        //Response.Write(strAttGroupID);
                        //Response.Write("AttDate");
                        //Response.Write(strAttendanceDate);
                        //Response.Write("Action");
                        //Response.Write(strAction);
                        //Response.End();

                        SqlCommand cmdInsertData = new SqlCommand("sp_AttendanceTaking", con);
                        cmdInsertData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                        cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AttGroupID", SqlDbType.Int));
                        cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Action", SqlDbType.VarChar));
                        cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PeopleID", SqlDbType.Int));
                        cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChurchID", SqlDbType.Int));
                        cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AttendanceDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));



                        // Convert Strings to Int where needed 
                        if (Int32.TryParse(strAttGroupID.ToString(), out int intGroupID)) { }
                        if (Int32.TryParse(strPeopleID.ToString(), out int intPeopleID)) { }
                        if (Int32.TryParse(strChurchID.ToString(), out int intChurchID)) { }



                        //Response.Write(intAttendanceID);
                        //Response.Write("-");
                        //Response.Write(strAction);
                        //Response.End();

                        cmdInsertData.Parameters["@AttGroupID"].Value = intGroupID;
                        cmdInsertData.Parameters["@Action"].Value = strAction;
                        cmdInsertData.Parameters["@PeopleID"].Value = intPeopleID;
                        cmdInsertData.Parameters["@ChurchID"].Value = intChurchID;
                        cmdInsertData.Parameters["@AttendanceDate"].Value = strAttendanceDate;


                        con.Open();
                        cmdInsertData.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        con.Close();

                    }
                else
                {
                        string strAction = "DEL";

                        //Response.Write("DEL BoxIdx=");
                        //Response.Write(BoxIndex);
                        //Response.Write("and  ItmIdx=");
                        //Response.Write(ItmIndex);
                        //Response.Write(" |");

                        // Here is what we do if the Box is unchecked       
                        //Response.Write("Let's Remove it...");
                        //Response.Write(strPeopleID);
                        //Response.Write("aID");
                        //Response.Write(strAttendanceID);
                        //Response.Write("checkBoxPresent:");
                        //Response.Write(strCheckBoxPresent);
                        //Response.End();

                        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
                // First let's delete this Groups Data

                SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand("sp_AttendanceTaking", con);
                cmdDelete.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


                cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AttendanceID", SqlDbType.Int));
                cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Action", SqlDbType.VarChar));


                        // Convert Strings to Int where needed 
                if (Int32.TryParse(strAttendanceID.ToString(), out int intAttendanceID)) { }



                        //Response.Write(intAttendanceID);
                        //Response.Write("-");
                        //Response.Write(strAction);
                        //Response.End();

                        cmdDelete.Parameters["@AttendanceID"].Value = intAttendanceID;
                        cmdDelete.Parameters["@Action"].Value = strAction;


                con.Open();
                cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

                        // End delete data

                    }
                }

        }
//end of checkbox 

        }
```

It's obviously not complete as I'm just trying to get it to show the right data.  I did a test of the delete portion (When the box is unchecked) and it did not delete a specific record because the `EventArgs` returns all the checkbox values. If I change it to `DataListItemEventArgs` it returns specific rows but then I lose the functionality of the checkbox on check. I think I need to separate these but I am not sure how to accomplish this task.

Here is the functionality I am going for:
1. Setup the date and retrieve any attendance if already taken.

[Image of form that loads the AttendanceTaker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbo2H.png)

And a sample of the page I am going for with a large checkbox so it can be used on a tablet.

[Sample of AttendanceTaker page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtQOw.png)

I rewrote the code using the idea from selected answer.  This was the code that ended up working.

```
      // Checkbox Checked?
    protected void CheckBoxPresent_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        CheckBox ChkBxPresent = sender as CheckBox;
        Boolean ChkBxPresentState = ChkBxPresent.Checked;

        if (Int32.TryParse(ChkBxPresent.Attributes["AttendanceID"].ToString(), out int intAttendanceID)) { }


        // Let's gather the parameter data needed
        string strPeopleID = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["PeopleId"];
        string strAttendanceID = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["AttendanceID"];
        string strCheckBoxPresent = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["IsChecked"];
        string strAttGroupID = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["SoCID"];
        string strAttendanceDate = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["AttendanceDate"];




        if (intAttendanceID == 0)  // Add Attendance Record it does not exist and was checked
        {
            string strAction = "ADD";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);

            SqlCommand cmdInsertData = new SqlCommand("sp_AttendanceTaking", con);
            cmdInsertData.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AttGroupID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Action", SqlDbType.VarChar));
            cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@PeopleID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ChurchID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdInsertData.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AttendanceDate", SqlDbType.DateTime));


            // Convert Strings to Int where needed 
            if (Int32.TryParse(strAttGroupID.ToString(), out int intGroupID)) { }
            if (Int32.TryParse(strPeopleID.ToString(), out int intPeopleID)) { }
            if (Int32.TryParse(strChurchID.ToString(), out int intChurchID)) { }


            cmdInsertData.Parameters["@AttGroupID"].Value = intGroupID;
            cmdInsertData.Parameters["@Action"].Value = strAction;
            cmdInsertData.Parameters["@PeopleID"].Value = intPeopleID;
            cmdInsertData.Parameters["@ChurchID"].Value = intChurchID;
            cmdInsertData.Parameters["@AttendanceDate"].Value = strAttendanceDate;


            con.Open();
            cmdInsertData.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            DataList1.DataBind();

        }
        else  // Delete Attendance Record it was unchecked
        {
            string strAction = "DEL";

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            // First let's delete this Groups Data

            SqlCommand cmdDelete = new SqlCommand("sp_AttendanceTaking", con);
            cmdDelete.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;


            cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@AttendanceID", SqlDbType.Int));
            cmdDelete.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Action", SqlDbType.VarChar));


            cmdDelete.Parameters["@AttendanceID"].Value = intAttendanceID;
            cmdDelete.Parameters["@Action"].Value = strAction;


            con.Open();
            cmdDelete.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            DataList1.DataBind();
            // End delete data

        }

    ////end of checkbox
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass the value of the PeopleId (and/or attendanceID) in the checkbox as an attribute and avoid iterating over the DataList.

Your checkbox

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBoxPresent" runat="server" PeopleId='<%# Eval("PeopleID") %>' Text='<%# Eval("CheckBoxPresent") %>' Checked='<%# Eval("CheckBoxPresent").ToString().Equals("1") %>' CssClass="ChkBoxClass" OnCheckedChanged="CheckBoxPresent_CheckedChanged" AutoPostBack="true"  />
```

Code behind

```
string strPeopleID = ChkBxPresent.Attributes["PeopleId"];
```

Then if it's checked, issue insert command for that ID only, if it's unchecked, issue delete command for that ID.

Comment: Sea Charp, That puts me on the right path!  Now I am not just getting the first id of the list.  Thanks so much for taking time to read the wall of text and coming up with exactly what I was trying to accomplish. :)

Comment: I have another question.  I am passing the AttendanceRecord ID on the delete so I am only deleting that single row.  But when i insert, I insert  as many total number of rows that do not have checkboxes in the DataList.  Is there a way to isolate the id of the specific checkbox to only insert 1 row.

Comment: I don't understand. Can you edit the original question to include your modified code?

Comment: Ok.  I edited it to include the changes I made.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks again Sea Charp, I was able to get on the right path with your help.